# Can I use an oven instead of a dehydrator to prepare lentils for milling at home

Tags: dehydrating, milling

Can I use an oven instead of a dehydrator for grains and pulses?  Dehydrators are not so common in my neck of the woods.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've heard you might be able to if your oven can be set on 170 degrees Fahrenheit and left propped open with a wooden spoon or something so the air escapes better

Comment: Just tried making my own chile powder out of ripe Anaheims. Sliced them and tried drying in a 170°F oven. Too wet, they started cooking, and I even got some burning to bottom of pan. Had to finish the job with my much cooler dehydrator. The cooking and sticking is likely a common problem with the moister foods. JFYI, when dried and ground, I got *excellent* chile powder.

Comment: Yeah there's still a problem using the oven, there's lack of good air flow and less options for lower temperatures. It's a really strange decision by oven makers to not allow you to cook at a lower temperature. I've seen people hack ovens before to make them cook at really hot temperatures, but not cooler. I wonder if there's a way?

Comment: I was baffled last time I bought an oven, that none of them seem to come with a dough-raising setting.

Comment: I would love to use my oven as a proofer. If only :(

Answer (score 2):

Using ovens as a dehydrator is pretty universal for any kind of food that can be dried.

Here is just one of many sites out there -

[How to make sprouted grain flour](http://nourishedkitchen.com/how-to-make-sprouted-grain-flour/)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Andrew for your reply and link.
In the meanwhile I decided to try and see for myself.
I put some buckwheat on a flat surface in the oven for about 30 min.
I took the same amount of buckwheat and left it as is.
Then I tried milling the two batches.  The oven batch yielded flour much more quickly than the other, untreated batch.
One other suggested solution I found, was, to cook the lentils, puree the mass and dehydrate before milling.  I have yet to try this for myself.  We'll see...